# Cannot test cryptographic performance using crypto_aesni_mb

Tags: cryptography, dpdk, aes-ni, dpdk-pmd

Trying to test cryptography performance virtual crypto AES-NI MB PMD  using below command,

```bash
sudo ./dpdk-test-crypto-perf -c 0xf -n 4 --vdev crypto_aesni_mb -- --ptest throughput --devtype crypto_aesni_mb --optype cipher-then-auth --cipher-algo aes-cbc --cipher-op encrypt --cipher-key-sz 16 --auth-algo sha1-hmac --auth-op generate --auth-key-sz 64 --digest-sz 16 --total-ops 100000 --burst-sz 32 --buffer-sz 2048
```

Using below link I followed steps to enable the virtual crypto

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-20.11/cryptodevs/aesni_mb.html

```
EAL: failed to parse device "crypto_aesni_mb"
EAL: Unable to parse device 'crypto_aesni_mb'
```

Comment: This is probably better asked on e.g. [su], but check for dupes first. I don't see anything programming related. When you do, please clearly tag your code and output, e.g. see my [edit]. Don't put the word "I" in your question title and don't put any niceties in at the bottom.

Comment: Your question seems to be about a Linux system. Which distribution and version do you use? And what CPU do you use (does the GPU have AES ni support)?